# True or False: If $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=\infty$ then exists $M>0$ such that $a_{n+1}>Ma_n$ for almost all $n$?

Tags: calculus, limits, examples-counterexamples

> True or False: If $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=\infty$ then exists $M>0$ such that $a_{n+1}>Ma_n$ for almost all $n$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try $$ a_n=\begin{cases}n^2&n\text{ even}\\n&n\text{ odd}\end{cases}$$

Comment: That's actually exactly what I was trying :S maybe I'm just tired

Comment: I think I got it, since for every even n we get $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{n+1}/a_n=0$ we have a subseries such that for every $M>0$ we have $a_{n+1}/a_n<M$ from some point.

Answer (score 2):

What if you define $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ as $a_n=2n+n(-1)^n$?

Comment: Then any $M\in(0,1)$ will work.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I hadn't noticed that $M$ could be smaller than $1$. I've edited my answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Take $$u_{2n} = \ln n~~~u_{2n+1} = e^n$$